# Draw line while moving label from point feature

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, labeling

Point feature has a field name which is used to display information about the feature in map canvas. Label can be move with **label and diagram move** tool .At the time  of moving I want to draw the line from position of feature to the new location of the label . Is there any way using some existing tool or we need to make using pyqgis?

Comment: I suggest you look into `callout lines`.

Comment: @Erik thank you very much callout lines did the work.

Comment: Be sure to provide a unique ID before moving the labels, otherwise all labels will be stacked.

Comment: Thanks for the Details Erik.